# How to generate a random number without repeating the previous random number in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to generate a random number in flutter from a range say 0 to 500 without repeating the previous random number which was already picked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey. Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a code writing service. We help in solving errors and if you have no idea what to do, we give some hints. Do try to write some code, do some research as this is a very easy problem

Comment: make a `List` 0,1,2...499 and `shuffle()` it

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
List numbers = [];
List selectedNumbers = [];
int i = 0;
while (i<500){
  numbers.add(i);
  i++
}

numbers.shuffle()
selectedNumbers.append(numbers[0])
numbers.remove(numbers[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var list = List.generate(501, (int i) => i);                                                                                     
  list.shuffle();                             
  print(list);
```

easy and precise.